# Change position of icon right top corner of Google map which finds current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I waned to change the position of the image icon which is on Google map when clicked on it goes to current location just like plus and minus symbol. So how can change the position of these symbols.

I do not know what do we call that image icon. I tried to Google how to change position of that icon but no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**

```
View plusMinusButton = suppormanagerObj.getView().findViewById(1);
View locationButton = suppormanagerObj.getView().findViewById(2);

// and next place it, for exemple, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
// position on right bottom
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Comment: I am using fragment in xml like  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" /> </FrameLayout> in that case where should i use this.

Comment: I solved that i used suppormanagerObj.getView() and continued with same and worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Ya that's exactly what i did. Thanks. And one more help if you don't mind , there is also plus minus button below right . If i use above code it is just placing on top of that plus minus. Is there anyway i can the position of plus minus button.

Comment: @TusharPandey, Check out this how you get suppormanagerObj  : getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)